# WPF Orthographic Camera. Region of view

Tags: .net, wpf, camera, orthographic

I added Orthographic Camera to my project. I want to show my chart on screen proportional. For example height is 4 and width 4 (region from -2 to 2).

I set width to 4 and it perfectly fit my square in widht.
but i have problem with height. The chart top and bottom is always out of screen space.
Why this happens and how to set to camera view the same width and height ?

Camera position: 0,0,5
Viewport have size: 571.5x497

On image we can see on vertical axis points from 2 to -2 but on vertical much more. How to make them same?

Image: http://i076.radikal.ru/1003/96/273c74ed9add.png

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Viewport have size: 571.5x497

The viewport must be square.

Answer (score 1):

You have said that you want to show a square region (4 x 4) but your viewport isn't square.

Unless you make your viewport square you'll have to either have blank areas (like the letter box on a widescreen movie) or clipping.